# Re-index flat tables without having them enabled?

Tags: database, reindex

Is it possible to reindex flat product and category tables without having them enabled?  I need to enable them but it hasn't been done in 2 years so don't want to leave a live site for 20 mins+ with products and data from 2015!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to reindex through the command line?

For example Flat Category:

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_flat
```

And for Flat Product:

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_flat
```

Comment: I haven't, will try that now

Comment: did it solve your problem?